Do you know how to fix this issue I have with brightness?
This happened on both Fedora and Ubuntu, both X11 and Wayland on Ubuntu. I'm not sure under what conditions it happens, but it has something to do with my laptop's screen waking up after going black. Brightness would set itself to max without the brightness slider displaying this. Interacting with the slider partially fixes it, but the slider breaks and brightness stops decreasing at around its halfway point and gets stuck at around 50% no matter how far left I go; /sys/class/backlight/nvidia_wmi_ec_backlight/brightness and actual_brightness files change accordingly, but brightness doesn't change. Restarting fixes it.

The title of the question should be more descriptive and avoind unnecessary wordiness.  The question text should follow the writing standards.

Make sure your Nvidia drivers are up to date. You can usually update them through your distribution's package manager or by downloading them directly from Nvidia's website.

@ShohagCellphonearea
sudo apt full-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
brightness-udev
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove it.
The following upgrades have been deferred due to phasing:
distro-info-data
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.

@ShohagCellphonearea i successfully updated and upgraded but it didn't fix it
